# What is the name of this database software?

Tags: mysql, database

I was googling around for this program, but no results, does anybody know what is the name of this database software?

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called HeidiSQL, a free and open source database browser for MySQL, MSSQL and PostgreSQL.

It can be downloaded from [here](https://www.heidisql.com/).

Comment: Where is the dolphin?

Comment: Dolphin? There is one (the MySQL logo) in the top left corner next to "Unnamed".